# How to get result from two combined tables

Tags: database, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have two tables:

Matches:

```
id   round league_id   home_team_id   away_team_id   match_date
```

Scores:

```
id  match_id    home_team_score   away_team_score    created_at  updated_at
```

How to get latest team match, which have record in table 'scores', for exmpl:

need to get last match where team_id = 1

with this i get all matches of this team, but i need only the last,and where has record in scores table:

```
$lastMatch = Match::where('away_team_id', '=', '1')
        ->orWhere('home_team_id', '=', '1')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get latest record from some table, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Model::latest()->first();
```

or

```
Model::latest('created_at', 'desc'))->first();
```

or

```
Model::orderBy('created_at')->first();
```

To get the result of two tables combined, you can join two tables, and then add `orderBy` or `latest` on the table and column you want.

So for the instance, in your case, that would be something like this:

```
Match::join('scores', 'matches.id', '=', 'scores.match_id')
       ->where('away_team_id', '=', '1')
       ->orWhere('home_team_id', '=', '1')
       ->latest('scores.created_at')->first()
```

Comment: thanks, also would be usefull, if u can ask me this question: how to check if scores table doesn't have related record? cuz i need to get latest match record without entered score.